# directshow architecture style

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture, directshow

I was doing some work with directshow recently and I noticed that it has kind of an interesting architecture. If you've ever worked with it, I think you'll know what I'm talking about. It's like any directshow object can be cast to any other directshow object. So, you can instantiate a filtergraph object, cast it to another object type to configure it, cast it to a media object to run the graph.

What's the name for this type of architecture scheme. It seems to involve interfaces or something. Where can I find out more about it? I'd like to use it in some software that I'm developing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called COM, [Component Object Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_object_model).